# Azure Async Python SDK Error when iterating through VM list

Tags: python, azure, api

I made a simple asynchronous python program to get the list of all Virtual Machines in a subscription. But I'm getting an error when iterating through the list.

The complete program:

```
from azure.identity.aio import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute.aio import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.aio import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.web.aio import WebSiteManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.sql.aio import SqlManagementClient
import asyncio

credential = AzureCliCredential()

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, "XXXXX")
web_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credential, "XXXX")

async def get_as_list():
    as_list = web_client.web_apps.list()
    async for _as in as_list:
        pass
    return as_list
async def get_vm_list():
    vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
    async for vm in vm_list:
        pass
    return vm_list

async def main():
    await get_as_list()
    await get_vm_list()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\Desktop\Work\Azure Inventory\Inventory with UI\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\Desktop\Work\Azure Inventory\Inventory with UI\test.py", line 28, in main
    await get_vm_list()
  File "c:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\Desktop\Work\Azure Inventory\Inventory with UI\test.py", line 22, in get_vm_list
    async for vm in vm_list:
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\.virtualenvs\Inventory_with_UI-ioU1jGkq\lib\site-packages\azure\core\async_paging.py", line 163, in __anext__   
    return await self.__anext__()
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\.virtualenvs\Inventory_with_UI-ioU1jGkq\lib\site-packages\azure\core\async_paging.py", line 157, in __anext__   
    self._page = await self._page_iterator.__anext__()
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\.virtualenvs\Inventory_with_UI-ioU1jGkq\lib\site-packages\azure\core\async_paging.py", line 99, in __anext__    
    self._response = await self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\.virtualenvs\Inventory_with_UI-ioU1jGkq\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\compute\v2022_08_01\aio\operations\_virtual_machines_operations.py", line 1486, in get_next
    request = prepare_request(next_link)
  File "C:\Users\Kristian-Laptop\.virtualenvs\Inventory_with_UI-ioU1jGkq\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\compute\v2022_08_01\aio\operations\_virtual_machines_operations.py", line 1471, in prepare_request
    _next_request_params["api-version"] = self._config.api_version
AttributeError: 'ComputeManagementClientConfiguration' object has no attribute 'api_version'
```

No problem iterating through the Web app list. I'm only getting the error with the VM list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
credential = AzureCliCredential()

compute_config = ComputeManagementClientConfiguration(credential, "XXXXX")
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(compute_config)
web_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credential, "XXXX")
```